# Rails self join with has_many through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Users can follow other Users through FollowingRelationship

I would like to be able to say

`User.first.followings` **and it returns a list of Users**

This is not working:

```
Class User

  has_many :following_relationships
  has_many :followings, through: :following_relationships, foreign_key: :following_id, source: :user

end

Class FollowingRelationship
  attr_accessible :following_id, :follower_id

  belongs_to :followings, class_name: "User"

end
```

`User.first.followings` gives this in console:

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "following_relationships" ON "users"."id" = "following_relationships"."user_id" WHERE "following_relationships"."user_id" = 1
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: following_relationships.user_id: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "following_relationships" ON "users"."id" = "following_relationships"."user_id" WHERE "following_relationships"."user_id" = 1
```

Anyone see what piece I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that `FollowingRelationship` model doesn't have any relation with `User`.
It should have `belongs_to :user` since you specify `source: :user`, shouldn't it?

I don't quite understand your models and relations between them but `belongs_to :followings` looks rather strange.
`belongs_to` uses singular form since it can't belong to more than one object.

**UPDATE 1**
To be more clear.
I think you should have

```
class FollowingRelationship
  …
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :follower
end
```

That means `followings_relationships` table should have `user_id` and `follower_id` columns.

**UPDATE 2**
After some conversation we have figured it out.
Here is the code you should have

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :fade_relationships, foreign_key: :faded_id

  has_many :fadings, through: :fade_relationships, source: :fading

end

class FadeRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :faded_id, :fading_id

  belongs_to :fading, class_name: "User"

end
```

Comment: I'd like to be able to say User.first.followings and it returns a list of Users

Comment: You say that FollowingRelationship has no relation with User. I have this in that class... belongs_to :followings, class_name: "User" ... I am establishing the relation with User there.

Comment: Yes, I haven't seen it initially. `User.first.followings` means that `followings` should be in `User` model not `FollowingRelationship`.

Comment: It is. `followings` is in User model. Please see the code above. I have all the code above very clearly. In User --> `has_many :followings, through: :following_relationships, foreign_key: :following_id, source: :use`

Comment: I have updated my answer please check it. Is it clear?

Comment: I have in my code very clearly that there is no `user_id` in the `following_relationships` table.

Comment: I have this code above in FollowingRelationship. `attr_accessible :following_id, :follower_id`

Comment: There is no `user_id` in FollowingRelationship class

Comment: That is why your code is not working)) Change your code to use `source: :following`.

Comment: There is no way to connect the tables with the columns I have?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122014/discussion-between-aleksey-and-slindsey3000).